# How to go from radio button checked indicator to full button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my wordpress plugin and I'm having a hard time with the radio buttons.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cd3wagvh/

I want to hide the radio buttons and instead change the background of the whole label when it is clicked.

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work.

This part in particular is not working as intended:

```
.pewc-checkbox-group-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Edit: I cannot edit the HTML as it's part of a WordPress plugin and that's how they have it.

Edit: I have the part of the php code where I can potentially reverse the order?

```
'<li><label for="%s"><input data-option-cost="%s" type="radio" name="%s[]" id="%s" class="pewc-radio-form-field" value="%s" %s>&nbsp;%s</label></li>',
```

My php is no good, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a working fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3smfLhk8/3/

---

First, you need spaces around the `+`. CSS uses spaces to differentiate elements.

Second, the CSS `element + next-element` only works for two elements that are placed one after the other, not nested elements like you have in your example. In fact, there is currently [no way to get the parent element via CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/3207826).

Instead of nesting the elements, you could structure the HTML with the `<input>` preceding the `<label>`, like so:

```html
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="first-option" value="option-1">
    <label for="first-option">First option</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="second-option" value="option-2">
    <label for="second-option">Second option</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

and use the `first-element:checked ~ second-element` selector.

```css
li input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

li label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

li input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I should have added that restructuring the html is not an option as it's a plugin for wordpress that I am messing around with.

Comment: That's unfortunate. What I said about CSS selectors still applies, so your best bet is probably using the shadow DOM's `input:before` and `input:after` and creating clickable and style-able elements with those.